# Interesting MYSQL puzzle t20

Tags: mysql

Assume I have a mysql table:

```
ID - int, auto-increment
Num - int
```

Num is a random integer between 1 and 100 chosen randomly before inserting the row into the table.  Let's say I have 1000 entries in the table.
For example:

```
1,65
2,23
3,87
4,99
5,75
6,45
etc.
```

From this, How can one get the id values of the top 20 num values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want all the IDs of the random numbers which occur most frequently:

```
select Num, COUNT(id) as cnt, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
from yourtable
group by Num
order by cnt desc 
limit 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id
from table
order by Num desc
limit 0, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM Table ORDER BY Num DESC LIMIT 20
```